# Remove Repeats or Group from QuerySnapshot

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

```
var postDocumentSnapshot = await 
  _alertsColllectionReference
    .document(myId)
    .collection('userAlerts')
    .orderBy('timestamp',descending:true)
    .limit(100)
    .getDocuments();
      if(postDocumentSnapshot.documents.isNotEmpty){
        var wild = postDocumentSnapshot.documents
          .map((snapshot)=> Alert.fromMap(snapshot.data,snapshot.documentID))
          .where((mappedItem)=>mappedItem.documentId!=null)
          .toList();
          wild.((a, b) => b.timestamp.compareTo(a.timestamp)); 
        return wild;
      }
     else {return [];}
```

So I'm gettting a QuerySnapshot

Collection is Alerts,
Doc is User,
CollRef is UserAlerts,
Doc is AlertForUser

Is there anyway to group alertforusers that have the same field of 'postId'?
I dont want to show the same alert over and over again for the same post.
i was thinking something like

```
wild.((a, b) => b.postId.compareTo(a.postId));
```